# Not able to log into salesforce org. Had enabled salesforce authenticator but lost my cell. Anyway to log into org and remove 2-way authenticator?

Tags: authentication

Not able to log into salesforce org. Had enabled salesforce authenticator but lost my cell. Any other way to log into org and remove 2-way authenticator ? Or Any way to log into org ?

Comment: Yup. There is a link on the Authenticator page for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

Check [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_removing_two-factor_key.htm&type=5) out:

> Besides Salesforce Authenticator, one other mobile authenticator app
>   that generates verification codes (one-time passwords) can be
>   connected to a user’s account at a time. If your user loses access to
>   the app by replacing or losing the mobile device, disconnect the app
>   from your user’s account. The next time your user logs in with
>   two-factor authentication, if no other identity verification method is
>   connected, Salesforce prompts the user to connect a new authenticator
>   app.
>
> 1. From Setup, enter Users in the Quick Find box, then select Users.
> 2. Click the user’s name.
> 3. On the user’s detail page, click Disconnect next to the App Registration: One-Time Password Generator field.

An admin from your org can do it for you

Comment: But for this one, We will need to log into salesforce. Salesforce org is not allowing me to log into without salesforce authenticator token.  I dont have any user which can be used as well.